# Eclipse set up issues

Tags: android, eclipse

I've just downloaded the current Android ADT from the Android website. When I go into the eclipse folder and start a new Android application, my project always has two errors complaining that android.R has not been imported.

When I import android.r I still get two errors that complain about the follow lines of code (again, these are pre-written when I start the project):

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

The errors I get are as follows:

```
activity_main cannot be resolved or is not a field  
main cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

When I fix the first line I it suggests that I change it to the following:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_item);
```

But the compiler has nothing to suggest for the R.menu.main issue so I just comment it out.

Additionally, my folder structure doesn't have a bin folder:

[image]

[I've been trying to follow a video that shows how to make an Android plug in for Unity](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s1Mle2ERiuQ) which was created just back in August and the author of the video doesn't have any of these issues.

Is it just my eclipse that is messed up? 
Are there things I'm missing when I create a new project? (I set my project up with the default values selected)
What can I do to stop these issues from happening each time I start a new android project?

*edit*

Here is the activity_main.xml that gets automatically generated when I start a new project, again, I haven't touched this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your layout xml is properly written, just try running it once. The R.java file will get generated afresh and then errors should go away.

Comment: I don't touch any of the code, I just hit run and it says it can't due to the errors. However, I shall upload the xml file it creates so someone with more experience with this can see.

Comment: Try closing and restarting eclipse as well, this is apparently a common error. I faced it a lot too.

Comment: Also try creating a new project and put all your codes there.

Comment: Just done both. Closed and opened up eclipse; same error. deleted old project, made a new one, instantly closed and re-opened; same errors.

Comment: This is very pesky bug. Do you get the red underlining below R in your code in eclipse when it shows error?

Comment: I do indeed. Then when I include R it changes to the highlighted lines i mention above.

Comment: Try to go to R.java file and add those members. This is **not** advisable, but just check if it works. Click on the underline R and go there.

Comment: I've done that already my friend but that leads to other issue which I outline in my question :)

Comment: You might have already done this, but try cleaning your project. :)